# Exact type match in Java generics

Tags: java, generics

The following Java code is valid - no compile- or run-time errors.

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(
      new Comparator<>("hello", 5).areEqual()
    );
  }

  private static class Comparator<T> {

    private final T left;
    private final T right;

    public Comparator(T left, T right) {
      this.left = left;
      this.right = right;
    }

    public boolean areEqual() {
      return left.equals(right);
    }
  }
}
```

I expect the values `"hello"` and `5` are casted to `Object`, which is a common parent.

Is there a way to write the class in such a way that passing other than objects of the same type causes a compile-time error? I.e. passing objects casted to a common ancestor not allowed.

Comment: No. What is "exact same type"? I would also avoid calling your experimental classes the same things as well know classes from the JDK.

Comment: What do you mean by `accepted`? The comparator returning `true` or the code compiling?

Comment: Why don't you specify `T` when you create the `Comparator`? Change `new Comparator<>("hello", 5)` to `new Comparator<String>("hello", 5)` and you get a compile timer error. That's the whole point of generics.

Comment: @Robert Not really. The `Comparator` class is the piece of code I'm designing, the `main` method is client code, which I want to allow other people to produce. Or, more precisely, disallow them to produce combinations which don't make sense - I only want to allow comparing apples to apples.

Comment: Well, normally one uses [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) to enforce self types in Java - so `Comparable<T extends Comparable<T>>` for example; obviously that requires that the type be the one doing the comparison rather than an external type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really, no.

Because your generic type is unbound, there's only one common ancestor: `Object` - as you correctly surmise.

The only thing you can realistically do in this scenario is ensure that `equals` is correctly defined for objects you want to pass through this method.  You would also want to handle cases in which you pass `null` as an argument, too.

Answer (score 2):

Just specify the type in the generic parameters...

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(
      new Comparator<String>("hello", 1).areEqual()
    );
  }

  ...
}
```

If you do this with your current code, you will get a compiler error.

When you leave it unspecified, Java does not bother doing any type checking and simply uses the super type (`Object`) as the type for both.

---

You will also find the same issue when you do something like:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.asList("hello", 1)); // Will compile
```

vs

```
System.out.println(Arrays.<String>asList("hello", 1)); // Will not compile
```

Answer (score 1):

So, I think it is not possible by using generic. But you can restrict it by checking the Object type in the constructor like below code.

```
public Comparator(T left, T right) {
    if(left.getClass()!=right.getClass()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("All values passed needs to be object of same class");
    }
    this.left = left;
    this.right = right;
}
```

However, this will not give you compile time error but it will through Exception when a different type of object passed to the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

As @Makoto already answered, the short answer is **no**.

If you look at code snippet for `equals` method in your favorite IDE then you'll see that it has line like `if (getClass() != another.getClass()) return false;` It means that you check class of object inside `equals`. You could do the same at `areEqual` method but probably it's not needed - it should be implemented on another level