# Unable to match generic types in method parameters

Tags: java, generics, lambda

I don't know if the title is understandable but I have this:

```
    public class Product {
        public Integer getId() {...}
        public String getName() {...}
    }

    public <T,V> static void method(Function<T, V> f, V value) {...}
```

and I want to become a compile error when:

```
    method(Product::getId, "some String"); // id is not String
    method(Product::getName, 123);         // name is not Integer
```

But the compiler interpret V as:

```
java Serializable & Comparable<? extends Serializable & Comparable<?>>
```

It compiles but depending on how "method" is implemented, you get an Exception at runtime or it just works wrongly.

How can I instruct the compiler to match the wanted data type?
and I don't want to write a "method" for every possible V type.

Thanks!

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48723541/exact-type-match-in-java-generics) answer your question?

Comment: @AndrewVershinin not really, because they suggest to implement the method like Object.equals but it happens at runtime and I want it at compiling time. But thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enforce the generics by splitting them up accross two method calls, for that you'd need a new class:

```java
public class Value<T, V> {
    private final Function<T, V> f;
    
    public Value(Function<T, V> f) {
        this.f= f;
    }

    public void with(V value) {
        // move your code from method() into here
    }
}
```

And then change `method()` to something like this:

```java
public static <T, V> Value<T, V> method(Function<T, V> f) {
    return new Value<>(f);
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```java
method(Product::getId).with("123");   // compiler error
method(Product::getName).with(123);   // compiler error
method(Product::getId).with(123);     // no error
method(Product::getName).with("123"); // no error
```

Comment: An extra class and an extra method callback but it does the trick. Thanks!